# Invite user(s) to event with notification - works manually but not with Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I'm currently experiencing some problems with the Graph API when inviting users to an event. The users are being invited successfully, but they do not receive a notification of the invite.

However, if I manually invite a user from the event page they do get a notification.

Is this a known bug? Or is there a known workaround to get it working?

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug - event invites sent via the API don't result in an on-site notification.

They do increment the counter on the 'events' bookmark and add the event to the user's events list, but they don't appear in the notifications jewel or result in an email notification being sent out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Igy. We went months with this not working (I carried on working assuming it was a bug), but maybe 2/3 weeks ago when I was working on our app the notifications - to my surprise - were being sent. I wonder if they were testing it and then shut it off again - either way, it's another feature to add to the wishlist. Thanks!

Comment: @sean: Please adive. How to invite app users to a FB event? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug and it has been around for a while.

There is no on-site notification and event is not appearing in my friend's calendar. But ... if I delete my event all friends I've invited via API receive cancellation notification on site and via email.